# Laravel 6 Testing - Unknown database ':memory:'

Tags: laravel, sqlite, phpunit

For some reason my application can't use `:memory:` as the database while testing is printing the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ':memory:'`

How can I get my test to use database in memory? I have looked on Stack Overflow, LaraCast, and Reddit but haven't found a solution. Is there an alternative way to do this?

**PhpUnit.xml**

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

**config/database.php**

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    //'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
],
```

I have run `php artisan config:clear` & `cache:clear`.

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: @KennyHorna Through CLI using vendor/bin/phpunit --filter="myTestCase"

Comment: Did you try to specify the config file? `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter="myTestCase" --configuration phpunit.xml`

Comment: yeah same error occures

Comment: Check [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/phpunitxml-not-being-read-using-variables-from-env?page=1), maybe it could help you

Comment: @KennyHorna Nope only confirmed that I am using testing env

Answer (score 1):

So eventually decided to remove the `<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>` which kind of worked but still gave misc errors, but it made me realize that my `phpunit.xml` was not overriding my database connection.

So the long and short of the story is I ended up creating a testing connection that uses the `:memory:` database which worked.

```
'testing' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
],
```

As to what was initially preventing it from working the standard way of doing it I still don't know. but this resolved my issue.